# Mysql : workaround for if() returning >1 row

Tags: mysql

Having this where clause :

The first and second placeholder ? can have values : `1 || NULL`
The third place holder is dynamically added (array)

```
IF(ISNULL(?),1,xy.id) IN 
     (IF(ISNULL(?),1,(SELECT x.id FROM x WHERE name IN (?))))
```

I need this type isnull checking because i want the clause to always return true if data sent is null. Basically if data is null clause will be `1 IN 1` , if its not null find the corespondent ids , but `if()` function limits me to return only 1 result (not a set) .What options do i have here except dynamically build the whole query in php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your `where` clause

```
WHERE (ISNULL(?) OR xy.id IN (SELECT x.id FROM x WHERE name IN (?)))
```